# RegEx for double and integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the RegEx `/^([0-9]{1,}.[0-9])|([0-9],[0-9])$/` for double positive, but it doen't seem to be working properly. Oh yeah, I'm checking both, comma and dot as a separator.

And how to add for double negative.

For integer it's easier I guess, like `/^[0-9]$/`
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "not properly"?

Comment: Can you please give a quick example of what you are trying to match against?

Comment: You need to escape the `.` in your regex, `[\^$.|?*+()` are all special characters in regex and should be preceded by `\\ ` if they are to be used as literals outside of a character class.

Comment: Double: `/\d+[.,]\d+/` Integer: `\d+`

Comment: You are only allowing 1 or more digits before the period, but not after. You also only allow multiple digits if used with the `.` but not the `,`. In any case, notyourtype's answer is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? Optional minus, followed by an integer, followed by a dot or coma, followed by another integer:

```
/^-?[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?$/
```

Comment: And if you don't want to allow ints, just remove the parens and last question mark `(         )?`

Comment: what does + mean here actually? Especially the second one?

Comment: It means 'once or multiple times'. `?` = 0 or 1 time, `+` = 1 or multiple times, `*` = 0, 1, or multiple times

Comment: @notyourtype and just once? [.,] - should be presented one time, we don't put anything? He knows by default?

Comment: If you guys know a website I could learn something about RegEx, plzzzz, I would look up why we put [],{} etc.
Merci!!

Comment: Do you speak french? [This tutorial is a good start](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/dynamisez-vos-sites-web-avec-javascript/les-expressions-regulieres-1-2) and you can test your regular expressions at [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Comment: I do, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This regex match both: integer and double values (positive or negative) and check for both, comma or dot as a separator:

```
-?\d+[,.?\d+]*
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+\.\d+$
```

With this you can check if string is double value.